# Как из новой ветки убрать изменения, попавшие в неё из старой? git rebase?

Tags: git, typescript, git-rebase

столкнулся с такой ситуацией, создал ветку для новой задачи, поневнимательности создал её из старой ветки, запущил изменения и увидел коммиты со старой ветки. Как удалить старые коммиты? мне говорят читать git rebase. Что можете подсказать?

Comment: откатить до момента слияния

Comment: Читайте git rebase.

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно понимаете сущность веток. Ветка — это не хранилище коммитов, а указатель на место в истории, который перемещается при добавлении новых коммитов.

Если вы создали ветку не от того места, то можно пересадить цепочку коммитов куда нужно через rebase.

```
git rebase --onto <правильное начало ветки> <ошибочное начало ветки> <ветка>
```